# Amazon S3 direct upload with specify content type is ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to do direct upload to Amazon S3 using PHP. I want to do content type restriction while uploading the files but Amazon S3 seems like ignoring the S3 policy, but no error message displayed.

here is my policy setup

```
 return new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4($s3_client, $bucket,
        [
            'acl' => 'public-read', 
            'key' => 'files/shop_manager/' . $merchant_id . '/${filename}',
            'success_action_redirect' => $redirect_url,
            'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
        ],
        [
            [ 'acl'     => 'public-read' ],
            [ 'bucket'  =>  $bucket ],
            [ 'starts-with', '$key', 'files/shop_manager/' . $merchant_id],
            [ 'starts-with', '$success_action_redirect', $redirect_url],
            [ 'starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'text/'], 
            [ 'content-length-range', 1, 10485760] //10MB
        ]
    );
```

here is the generated form

```
<form id="formUpload" action="https://uboux-dev.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="files/shop_manager/274/${filename}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="https://merchants.uboux.com/management/media/?uboux_merchant_s3=7711ddf885" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="text/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAI4X5PXQ5KUE5RCXA/20180524/ap-southeast-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="20180524T020742Z" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxOC0wNS0yNFQwMzowNzo0MloiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LHsiYnVja2V0IjoidWJvdXgtZGV2In0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRrZXkiLCJmaWxlc1wvc2hvcF9tYW5hZ2VyXC8yNzQiXSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJHN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3JlZGlyZWN0IiwiaHR0cHM6XC9cL21lcmNoYW50cy51Ym91eC5jb21cL21hbmFnZW1lbnRcL21lZGlhXC8/dWJvdXhfbWVyY2hhbnRfczM9NzcxMWRkZjg4NSJdLFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwidGV4dFwvIl0sWyJjb250ZW50LWxlbmd0aC1yYW5nZSIsMSwxMDQ4NTc2MF0seyJYLUFtei1EYXRlIjoiMjAxODA1MjRUMDIwNzQyWiJ9LHsiWC1BbXotQ3JlZGVudGlhbCI6IkFLSUFJNFg1UFhRNUtVRTVSQ1hBXC8yMDE4MDUyNFwvYXAtc291dGhlYXN0LTFcL3MzXC9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSx7IlgtQW16LUFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifV19" /><input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="caadf7304062acb32ef82b08988e72801b368758dc32549ff4d2bbf08134f028" />       
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as intended.

The form has `<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="text/" />`, and that value matches the policy `[ 'starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'text/']`.

The problem is that you are assuming this feature does something that it doesn't actually do.

This feature isn't intended to actually restrict the content types that can be uploaded.  It is intended to restrict the content type you are *claiming* to be uploading, via the value placed in the form.  In other words, the user (or Javascript) can't change the form field to a value that conflicts with the policy.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so how do I implement content type restriction while uploading the files ?